# What is the best way to test primality of this number $123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282931$ for high school level?

Tags: prime-numbers, education, primality-test

I found that the number : $$123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282931$$ which is prime number , I want to know if there is any simple method to show students its primality ?

Comment: Ask Wolfram alpha

Comment: It is divisible by $29$

Comment: sorry , I edited i have deleted 30

Comment: I have included the $30$

Comment: You could use a [primality certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate), but it would be better to use a smaller example for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: In this case, we have to trust the computer. Even a probable prime test of this number by hand would be an enormous task.

Comment: Do you want to present this number to the classroom for discussion or is it only of interest if you can demonstrate that it is a prime?  Seems like a fun number to put up and claim that "it ain't easy to show it is a prime", then discuss why in high school level terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For high school level, showing non-primality is fair game, provided simple divisibility criteria can resolve it.

Showing primality for a number such as the one you posted is definitely *not* fair game.

One guideline would be: If the teacher can't show it easily, then it's not appropriate for students.

Answer (score 2):

The number is a prime. This cannot be found out in reasonable time without a computer.

Comment: To back this claim up: the [largest known primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number) before the advent of the electronic computer give an indication of what's feasible to do by hand. All of them are essentially Mersenne primes and largest of them is a mere $\approx 10^{38}$. OP's prime is *not* a Mersenne prime and is $\approx 10^{50}$ so it's very unlikely to have an easy proof.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't practical. Without knowing every prime below about $10^{25}$ you can't do simple divisibility testing (even if you could do it all before the universe ends). Even sieving with a $$6k\pm1$$ sieve adapted from the sieve of sundaram you would either need to type out more than $10^{24}$ numbers and sieve them as you go, just to get base primes. Primorial base change only helps to a point.  Beyond which a primality check of some form must be known. Preferable a fast one.

For a comparison , I wrote out all numbers up to 800 ( might go a bit further) but even if I do a sieve based on form, I'll only get all primes under about 4900 back. it's taken me about a week on and off. Yours would take a lifetime.  Have fun trying to teach primality checks.  even mod 30 we have 6 equations for it's mod 30 class to check.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult for high-school, and impossible without computers. That being said, $with$ computers, you can apply the [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test) with the number $a=2$. Note that the factorization of $n-1$ is
$$n-1 = 2×3×5×13×49269439\times 370677592383442753 \times 17333107067824345178861$$